# python boolean key for a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean, boolean-logic

I want to use a group of booleans as a key for a dictionary so (weather == sunny and temp == warm) would be 11 or True,True while (weather == sunny and weather == cold) would be 10 and (weather == cloudy and weather == cold) True,False would be 00 where clothing = {11:"shorts", 10:"jeans", 00:"jacket"} Is there a way to do this? I assume it might require bit manipulation, and I am trying to keep this as fast as possible for operation time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't actually need to do bitwise operations on the individual conditions (i.e., you don't need to AND/OR two conditions together), it may be simpler to just use a tuple of booleans as the key:

```
clothing = {
    (True, True): "shorts",
    (True, False): "jeans",
    (False, False): "jacket"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use bitwise or (`|`) operator:

```
sunny = 0
cloudy = 1
cold = 2
clothing = { (cold|cloudy) :"shorts", cold:"jeans", sunny:"jacket"}

weather = something()

print(clothing[ weather & (cold|cloudy) ])
```

but the tuple version suggested by @BrenBarn is better.